# How to set value in an object array in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question about how to set a element value in an object array.

this object array looks like this:

```
objArr = [

{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "abc"


},
{
  "id": "null",
  "name": "null"


}


];
```

now I want to replace the object to just like this

``````
objArr = [

{
  id: "123",
  name: "abc"


},



];
`````
that means, remove all object in array, which value is null

any solutions?
``````

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the values that you dont want in the array:

```js
objArr.filter(item => item.id === "null" && item.name === "null");
```

If you want to rewrite the same array, that would be:

```js
objArr = objArr.filter(...);
```

However, here I'm checking not for null values, but for objects that have both properties to a string "null". If you want to check for `null` objects, you would have to change the condition to be `(item === null)`.

Comment: actually you need to store the result somewhere `const x = objArr.filter(...)` where x is the new shallow copied array

Comment: hi Thx for your answer, It is possible that there are 20 elements (key and value) in a object, do you have any idea to check all elements instead item.id !== null && name &&...

Comment: Do you mean to check if all keys have null values?

Comment: `this.objArr.filter(item=>Object.keys(item).map(key=>item[key]).find(value=>value!="null"));`

Comment: Hi I got this error: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'my object'

Comment: Instead of ```Object.keys(item).map(key=>item[key])```, you can directly use ```Object.values(item)```. That'd be: ```objArr.filter((item) =>!Object.values(item).every((val) => val === "null"))```.

Comment: I will leave you this link to try it on your own: [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/javascript-forked-f0g8q1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: the other question, what happens if all keys are string?

Comment: I have tested with all key with type string. it did not work

Comment: you mean having the list like this: ```let objArr = [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "null",
    "name": "null"
  }
];``` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247504/discussion-between-user1938143-and-victorperezpiqueras).